# Custom tab or navigation bar in android

Tags: android, android-layout, tabs

I am trying to create a Tab or navigation bar in my application at the top of the screen ,which should look like this :

[image]

Is it possible to create this kind of tab ..How can i do this...

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes everything is possible in Android :) , i mean you can easily customize it, better you go through this example first: [Custom Android Tabs](http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=136).

As you want to customize tab bar with rounded border in tab, you need to concentrate on Step-3 and Step-4 given in above example.

Comment: thanks for quick response paresh,i tried to create custom tabs ,but i stuck  when i tried to show tab at the middle of the screen , and open the tab content in full screen width ....

Comment: @nibha without checking what you have done, how can i suggest where you stuck and where you made mistake?